# why codeigniter do_upload doesn't work on server?

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I have used codeigniter do_upload to upload mp3 files on a directory on server.
my codes work perfectly on localhost but on production server just browser keeps waiting for server and processing and nothing happens after a long time.

$dirpath in following code is the path of destination directory on server.

```
    $data['info']=$this->cp_model->GetInfo($service_id);
    $dirpath = '/var/li/sounds/'.$data['info'][0]->path;


    $config = array('allowed_types' => 'mp3' ,
                    'upload_path' => $dirpath,
                    'overwrite' => FALSE,
                    'max_size' => 0,
                    );

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $this->upload->do_upload();}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have writing permissions in the `$dirpath`directory?

Comment: Try to add `$this->upload->initialize($config);` immediately  after `$this->load->library('upload',$config);`.

Comment: @repptilia can you explain more about your suggestion pleas?

Comment: @hodhod If you are not authorized to write on server, upload cannot happen, as your script will not be able to write on the server.

Comment: @repptilia the directory is writable by user and its' permission is :drwxrwxrwx

Comment: Is the files reaching the server? Check your $_FILES array.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't have write permissions on the folder declared on your $dirpath. Also consider that uploading an mp3 that may be 4-5 MB server side, can take some minutes depending your connection.

To find out what your problem is whatsoever, output your error by checking the do_upload() method.

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
```

More information on the [File Uploading class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

Comment: I used $this->upload->display_errors() too but it doesn't work for me,still browser is processing and nothing happens. I also checked directory permission,it's chmod is 777.

Comment: Try uploading a very small mp3 file (100-200kb max). Also make sure that you don't have a small limit in your post_max_size and your upload_max_filesize variables in your php.ini file.

Comment: I uploaded a 19kb mp3 file,nothing changed :(

Comment: in this case,process stops after a while but file is not uploaded in $dirpath.

Comment: Change your `$dirpath` to a directory that is writable by the user that runs the webserver. Ofc this depends on your server configuration.

Comment: the directory is writable by user and its' permission is :drwxrwxrwx

Answer (score -3):

Your script works everywhere beside "Local" server
Now I had the same problem, tested it in Hosting Web Server, and it worked. If u wanna the code, here u are:

```
public function do_upload()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './img';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config["encrypt_name"] = true;
    $config["remove_spaces"] = true;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_view', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```